# Oracle procedure to update a row and return its key?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Seems like this should be easy, but the syntax eludes me.  I am trying to update an existing row -- the first one I find that is 'New'.  Then I want to return a delimited string having the key and 2 other values:

```
create or replace procedure usp_direct_print_task_deque 
(
  taskNa in char
 ,environmentCd in char
) as 
begin
  declare rowkey number;

  select '~' || rowversion || '~' || target_document || '~' || target_printer 
   as delimited_data
   , rowversion 
  from AFD1.bt_direct_print_tasks
  where environment_cd = environmentCd 
   and task_na = taskNa  
   and task_status = 'new'
   and rownum = 1;

  update bt_direct_print_tasks
  set taskStatus = 'processing'
  where rowversion = rowkey;

  return delimited_data;  

end usp_direct_print_task_deque;
```

Comment: Are you getting a syntax error? Could you please post it if you are?

Comment: where is rowkey coming from ?

Comment: Good find!  I deleted the 'declare rowkey number;' statement.  Rowkey is rowversion -- I renamed it just to make it clear that this is using a synthetic key.

Comment: You can just run an update directly against bt_direct_print_tasks to assign '~' || rowversion || '~' || target_document || '~' || target_printer to delimited_data, and have the update return the new value. Rather more efficient https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define OUT parameters variables, say `x_delimited_data` and `x_rowkey` to hold the values for `delimited_data` and `rowkey`, respectively.  Then change your `SELECT` to `SELECT... INTO x_delimited_data, x_rowkey`.  (I'm assuming rowkey is what you are selecting as `rowversion`).  Then change `return delimited_data;` to just `return;`

Comment: Thanks Matthew!  You nailed it.